# Getting Shoutcast Metadata in Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, shoutcast

I currently have an appengine application set up that polls a Shoutcast station's 7.html file and saves the result. However, I have recently come across some stations which are running Shoutcast version 2.0 and don't seem to support the 7.html method.

So how can I somehow retrieve the metadata from such servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to current ShoutCast v2 docs you should be able to call:

```
http://blah:port/currentsong?sid=<streamid>
```

If you don't know the streamid (ShoutCast v2 adds stream multiplexing), you can get http://blah:port/index.html for a list of active stations on that port and their id's.

More details at:
http://dev.winamp.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_DNAS_Server_2#Administration_Pages